# Ambiguous match found exception in BindingListView

Tags: c#, reflection, data-binding

I keep getting this exception while using Andrew Davey's BindingListView (http://blw.sourceforge.net/). I am using ServiceStack OrmLite . My objects looks like this:

```
public class Category
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Product
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [References(typeof(Category))]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int ProductTypeId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Reference]
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

I have no idea how to pass this exception.

### Edit

The exception occurs on the first line of the following code:

```
var products = dbConn.Select<Product>().OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToList();
var productsView = new BindingListView<Product>(products);
dgProducts.DataSource = productsView;
```

Comment: can you show the code where the error occurs?

Comment: I just editet the question and added the code.

Comment: I'm at the same page. The error just happens at line 2024 of AggregateBindingListView.cs: return Activator.CreateInstance(viewType, list);

Comment: In the meantime I found the issue. I had a `List<T>` in my class, which I had to intantiate it in the constructor. After that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

you have

```
product.Name
product.Category.Name

product.Id  
product.Category.Id
```

when that lib does reflection to get Property, it gets 2 "Name".

code doesnt know, Which one do you want.  Product.Name from or Product.Category.Name.

---

**tldr: easy fix** is  to change one of properties names

```
public class Category
{
    public int cId { get; set; }
    public string cName { get; set; }
}


public class Product
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [References(typeof(Category))]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int ProductTypeId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Reference]
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```